# How does AWS Athena react to schema changes in S3 files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, schema, amazon-athena

What happens when after creating the table in AWS Athena for files on S3, the structure of the files on S3 change?

For eg:

1. If the files previously had 5 columns when the table was created and later the new files started getting 1 more column:
   a) at the end?
   b) in between?
2. What happens when some columns are not available in new files?
3. What happens when the columns remain the same but the column order changes?
4. Can we alter Athena tables to adjust to these changes?

Answer (score 10):

1 - Athena is not a NoSQL solution. It is not dynamic schema either. If you change the schema, all your files in a particular folder should reflect that change. Athena wont magically update to have it included.

2 - Then it'll be a problem and it'll break. You should include `NULL` or `,,` to force it to be okay.

3 - Athena picks it up by column order. Not by name, really. If your column orders change, it'll probably break (different types).

4 - Yes. You can always easily recreate Athena tables by dropping it and creating a new one.

If you have variable length files, then you should insert them into different folders so that each folder represents one consistent schema. You can then unify this later on in Athena with a `union` or similar to create a condensed, simplified table that you can apply the consistent schema to.

Comment: 4. Dropping and recreating is not altering. I assume you wanted to imply No.

Comment: True. Fair point. Because the files of a table must all be consistent with the top level schema, it doesnt make sense per se to alter a table and add in new columns, as it would imply the base data would have had those columns in them in the first place

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the files format you are using and the setup (if the schema is by field order or by field name). All the details are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/handling-schema-updates-chapter.html
Take a big note that if the data is nested or in arrays, it will completely break your data, to quote from this page:

> Schema updates described in this section do not work on tables with complex or nested data types, such as arrays and structs.

Comment: In the link above you can see a table explaining the difference between the file formats